# Windows event log service records

Tags: windows, logging

When the Windows event log service is stopped or started is this logged anywhere on windows?
Service = EventLog

Comment: The question is off-topic on Security SE.

Comment: It depends if it was intentionally or unintentionally shut down. Please clarify.

Comment: @mentallurg  Could you explain how it offf topic on security forum? It was tagged with SIEM and windows. From what resource do you think SIEM(Security Information Event Manager) gathers logs on windows? Which service on windows must be working to look into logs on Windows? If your SIEM product can not gather windows event logs do not you investigate what happened or such?

Comment: @Avi why would it matter if it is intentional or not as to find out when Windows event log service stopped or started? It is a part of digitral forensics investigation - DFIR process to define a timeline? It could be a security breach intentional or unintentional that could lead again to a security breach, because I can not image why someone would stop windows from gathering logs intentionally, asssuming it is not malicious intention